# How to calculate three.js camera matrix given projection matrix

Tags: google-maps-api-3, three.js, webgl, geospatial

Problem context: I'm working on using the google maps webgl api with threejs wrapper to create an interactive browser game.

My understanding of the framework is that google maps takes control of the webgl camera (e.g., to enable the usual maps controls like drag-to-pan and scroll-to-zoom) and only allows client three.js code to query camera information via the following documented api:

```
    this.camera.projectionMatrix.fromArray(
      transformer.fromLatLngAltitude(this.anchor, this.rotation, this.scale)
    );
```

I've attempted to click on three.js objects using the following method for calculating projection rays:

```
 raycast(
    normalizedScreenPoint: three.Vector2,
  ): three.Intersection[] {
    
    this.projectionMatrixInverse.copy(this.camera.projectionMatrix).invert();
 
    this.raycaster.ray.origin
      .set(normalizedScreenPoint.x, normalizedScreenPoint.y, 0)
      .applyMatrix4(this.projectionMatrixInverse);

    this.raycaster.ray.direction
      .set(normalizedScreenPoint.x, normalizedScreenPoint.y, .5)
      .applyMatrix4(this.projectionMatrixInverse)
      .sub(this.raycaster.ray.origin)
      .normalize();
    ...
}
```

where normalizedScreenPoint ranges from -1 to 1 and is just the X/Y coordinates within the map div.

This method generally seems to be working correctly close to ground level. However, for objects at high altitudes (400m, or 400 threejs units) close to but not occluded by the camera (still entirely within the viewing frustrum), my projection rays are not intersecting these objects as expected. The problem gets even worse with altitude, with objects being nearly unselectable at 1000m. I do not have this issue when running in a pure three.js environment using three.js native functions for generating projection rays, which require the cameras position in three.js space to be known.

I have to believe there's so kind of coordinate mismatch between three.js cartesian coordinates and the google maps azimuthal projection, or some comparable issue that's leading to the api to return a "bad" projection matrix. The googlemaps hooks to webgl are closed-source, so I'm unable to dig in how the camera projection is generated, but I believe it'd be easier to be able to manually move the camera position up in height a few meters if I was able to set and calculate it. How could I do this given its projection matrix?

The other alternatives, of trying to integrate three.js myself with another map rendering engine like Tangram to give me full control, would resolve these issues of dealing with an proprietary api but presumably be much more time-intensive.